# Implementing fragments in Android

Tags: android, fragment

I am developing a application and in an activity I want it to be similar to the ICS settings application; i.e. on the left side I have a ListFragment with 4 categories, and on the right a Fragment with the content of each category, and each category has a different layout. I ran into a doubt: should I develop 4 different fragments for the categories and replace them according to the selected category, or there is a way to just use one Fragment for the content and use different layouts according to selected category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write separate fragments and switch them out as appropriate.

Doing so makes your code more modular and allows you to take advantage of existing Android APIs (e.g. [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to display your data.